# Using a variable in constant name

Tags: ruby

I have three constants:

```
MUTUAL_CATEGORIES
PROVIDER_CATEGORIES
RECEIVER_CATEGORIES
```

and a method that refers to the categories

```
def do_some_stuff_with_mutual
  MUTUAL_CATEGORIES ...
end
```

I want to abstract this method so I can do something like:

```
do_some_stuff_with(MUTUAL)

def do_some_stuff_with(type)
  (type + "_CATEGORIES") ...
end
```

How can I convert a string to refer to a constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.const_get(type + "_CATEGORIES")...`
Replace `Object` with the class where the constant is defined

Comment: perfect, thank you.  I should have considered it would be a class method.

Comment: ...so in the example, where it appears that `self => main`, `self.class => Object`, so use `Object` (or `self.class`) as the receiver for `const_get`.

Answer (score 1):

it's probably not a good idea but you could also use eval:

```
do_some_stuff_with(MUTUAL)

def do_some_stuff_with(type)
   eval(type + "_CATEGORIES").each_with_index do |item, index|
      #stuff for this type
   end
end
```